# JSON data can't get back via jquery each function

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

```
 $(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'image/show',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            $.each(function (i, item) {
                alert(item.ratio);
            });
        }
    });
 });
```

get data back like these:

```
{"id":2,"ratio":0.66666666666667,"src":"public\/media\/flickr\/13842755234_c8e89150b1_m.jpg"}{"id":3,"ratio":1.0491803278689,"src":"public\/media\/flickr\/13845062983_00fd2bebe2_n.jpg"}{"id":4,"ratio":1.5015015015015,"src":"public\/media\/flickr\/13845347184_24ca8d4e5d.jpg"}
```

QUESTION: I CAN'T ALERT DATA VIA MY JQUERY CODE.IS ANYTHING GOES WRONG IN MY CODES?

I think maybe these data format goes error.

```
public function show() {

    $dirname = "public/media/flickr/";
    $images = scandir($dirname);
    $ignore = Array('.',"..");

    foreach ($images as $key=>$curimg) {
        if (!in_array($curimg, $ignore)) {
            $imagefile = $dirname.$curimg;
            list($width,$height) = getimagesize($imagefile);    
            $ratio = $width/$height;
            $data = array(
                    'id' =>$key,
                    'ratio' => $ratio,
                    'src' => $imagefile);
            echo json_encode($data);
        }

    }
}
```

my php function error. I made a mistake in foreach.

Comment: Don't use capital letter, It is considered as shouting

Comment: I'd rather know what's wrong with your Caps Lock key.

Comment: Tried `JSON.parse(data)`?

Comment: Does the call enter `success` at all? Try the `error` callback as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
 alert(data.ratio);
```

There is no need of `.each()` here.

Full code,

```
 $(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'image/show',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.ratio);
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: He would need to use `alert(data["ratio"]);` I guess.

Comment: @GauravBhor why you are guessing like so..? both are same.. you are accessing the value using bracket notation.. that's all..\

Comment: @Gaurav, how would that be different?

Comment: This should clear the air http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation

Comment: @SanChen First make an empty alert inside the success call back.. There may be a problem in the server side code..

Answer (score 0):

Your $.each it wrong, it should be:

```
$.each(data, function(index, item) {
 alert(item.ratio)
})
```